# Sorting an array of arrays in javascript based on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multiple-columns

```
result = [['Houston','TX', 84],['Austin','TX', 84],['Los Angeles','LA', 84]];
```

The above is my code:

I want to sort this array alphabetically based on two fields, State and City.
The sorted array for above example should be:
    result = [['Los Angeles','LA', 84], ['Austin','TX', 84], ['Houston','TX', 84]];

Please suggest me a solution in JavaScript

Comment: I'm unable to relate to that. Can I have the explanation in my case with the answer @Derek

Comment: Your question is fundamentally the same as the one mentioned: both are sorting an array with two fields. If you need help with other parts such as how to use the `.sort` function, you might want to reformulate your question.